# Is there a 'this' type of selector in Lua like there is in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, lua

I'm trying to create a constructor.

```
DialogData_Constructor = {
  
    name = "", id = "", has_blocked = false, blocked_by = false, messages = { }, time_stamps = { },
    
    New = function()
        local tab = {}
        for i, v in pairs(DialogData_Constructor) do
            tab[i] = v
        end
        return tab
    end,

    AddNewMessage = function( message, time_stamp )
        table.insert ( .messages, message ) -- how do I insert new data into this table?
        table.insert ( .time_stamps, time_stamp)
    end
}
```

So my question is, how do you identify or select the table in AddNewMessage -function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing OOP in lua you want to use `:` syntax and the `self` variable.

[Programming in Lua: 16 – Object-Oriented Programming](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)

When you do `someTable:someMethod()` you are going to pass the table in as the first value it is syntactic sugar for `sometable['someMethod'](sometable)`

An additional thing to note while doing OOP in lua is to use `setmetatable` in your constructor.

With that known your class would look like this

```lua
DialogData_Constructor = {
  New = function(self)
    local o = { -- fields whose values are unique to each instance should be defined here.
      name = "", 
      id = "", 
      has_blocked = false, 
      blocked_by = false, 
      messages = { }, 
      time_stamps = { },
    }
    return setmetatable(o, {__index = self})
  end,

  AddNewMessage = function(self, message, time_stamp )
    table.insert (self.messages, message) 
    table.insert (self.time_stamps, time_stamp)
  end
}
```

And usage would look like this.

```lua
local mydialogData = DialogData_Constructor:New();
mydialogData:AddNewMessage("message", os.time())
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but this gives me "attempt to call method 'AddNewMessage' (a nil value)" Error. Any clues?

Comment: @Stybos My bad, forgot to structure the metatable. I corrected the error in the answers

Comment: I appreciate your help, everything runs smoothly now!